# Solutions to the equation $a^2x-b^2x^2=c^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, number-theory, field-theory

This is a middle step of my solution to a problem.But I don't know if this claim is right.

Let $a,b\in \mathbb Q$, and $x\in \mathbb Z$ be a square free integer. I want to show if $\mathbb Q(\sqrt {a^2-b^2 x})=\mathbb Q(\sqrt x).$Then $x$ is the sum of two rational squares.

Hence there exists some $c\in\mathbb Q$, such that $a^2x-b^2x^2=c^2$. So I have to work out the equation $a^2x-b^2x^2=c^2$, however I am not sure if it is true that one can always write $x=m^2+n^2$ for some $m,n\in \mathbb Q$?

Comment: May be this help: an integer $x$ is of the form $m^2+n^2$ with $m,n \in \Bbb Q$ if and only if $x$ is of the form $m^2+n^2$ with $m,n \in \Bbb Z$.

Comment: @jjagmath I tried to use the result, however I still cannot show the desired result.

Comment: I don't see how you get from ${\bf Q}(\sqrt{a^2-b^2x})={\bf Q}(\sqrt x)$ to $a^2x-b^2x^2=c^2$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson That's because $\mathbb Q(\sqrt a)=\mathbb Q(\sqrt b)$ iff $\sqrt {ab}\in \mathbb Q$

Comment: $a^2-b^2x=c^2x$ is $a^2=(b^2+c^2)x$. Let $p$ be a prime dividing $x$; suppose $p^k$ divides $x$ but $p^{k+1}$ doesn't. If $k$ is odd, then the power of $p$ dividing $b^2+c^2$ is also odd, so $p\equiv1\bmod4$, so $p^k$ is a sum of two squares. If $k$ is even, then $p^k$ dividing $x$ doesn't affect whether $x$ is a sum of two squares or not. So $x$ is a square times a product of sums of two squares, so it is a sum of two squares.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks, but I have a few questions. First, for primes $p,q$ if $p^k$ and $q^l$ are power of prime factors of $x$ and both can be written as sum of two squares where $k$ and $l$ are odd, why their product is also sum of  two squares? Second, since $a,b,c$ are rationals, the word $devide$ seems to be a little wired to me, we are doing division in $\mathbb Q$ and primes are invertible in $\mathbb Q$, especially, $p$ dividing $b^2+c^2$, I am a little bit confused about this.

Comment: If $u=v^2+w^2$ and $x=y^2+z^2$ then $ux=(vy+wz)^2+(vz-wy)^2$. This has nothing to do with primes. "devide"? "wired"? Every rational has a unique expression as a product of powers of distinct primes. Some of the powers may be negative. Doesn't matter – the concepts of even and odd apply as usual to negative integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a,b,c\in\Bbb{Q}$ and $x\in\Bbb{Z}$ squarefree such that
$$a^2x-b^2x^2=c^2.$$
Clearing denominators, we may assume without loss of generality that $a,b,c\in\Bbb{Z}$. Then we see that $x$ divides $c$, say $c=xw$, and in turn $x$ divides $a$, say $a=xu$, so that
$$u^2x=b^2+w^2.$$
This shows that $u^2x$ is a sum of two integer squares, where $u$ and $x$ are both integers. It now follows immediately from the characterization of integers that are sums of two squares, that also $x$ is a sum of two integer squares.

Comment: I see that $x$ divides $c^2$, but that doesn't imply that $x$ divides $c$ (unless $x$ is squarefree). How do you get that?

Comment: @GerryMyerson It follows from the assumption that $x$ is squarefree.

Comment: Ah, I missed that.